# Self-Hosted Blog on Google Search

Tags: google-search

I have a self-hosted blog, ([Code Repo - Code Snippets](http://dougmolineux.com/wp/)) but for some reason when I search for it on google, it doesn't come up in the results.

I posted an entry about 4 days ago, and by now I would have expected it come up in the results. When I search for things on my normal site (same domain), they do come up, its just things inside the blog that don't seem to be included.

In the past, I have only had blogs hosted on wordpress.com and they have always automatically come up.

What can I do to fix this?

Thank you!

Comment: Normally google picks WP sites up fairly quickly.  Have you done anything to help it along.  Like a sitemap (using a sitemap plugin) submitted to webmaster tools?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Googling "site:http://dougmolineux.com/wp/" seems to show that you blog is getting indexed and quick check doesn't find any settings prohibitive to indexing set.

Other than latter there isn't really much that can be done, it's up to Google how it indexes and serves your site in results.